# No Rational Solutions To Elliptic Curve System

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, rational-numbers

I was asked to show that the following system has no rational solutions:

$y^2 = 17 + 2x^2
\\
y^2 = 34 +z^2
$

That is to say, that there are no $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that the above relations hold.

---

My attempt:

It was fairly easy to show that there are no solutions over $\mathbb{Z}$ and this is where I pretty much got stuck.

ANY help would be appreciated

Comment: This is not about elliptic curves, this is “just” about two conics?

Comment: @Aphelli - this question was given as an example in intro to elliptic curves course, so I assumed there was some "elliptic curve approach". but as i wrote any direction will be helpful.

Comment: Hint: work mod $8$.

Comment: For your attempt, the equation(s) should be $y^2=34+x^3$ etc. Is there a typo?

Comment: No there was no typo, you are correct that my attempt was wrong, i edited the question

Comment: @Aphelli - I know there are no solutions over Z - could you explain how to derive there are no rational solutions as well by working mod 8?

Comment: I'd like to know more; what book is this from, and what are the lectures for the past few days about?

Comment: How about introducing the minimal denominator for $x,y,z$, and then checking mod eight?

Comment: @WillJagy -  the course follows the material from Silverman's "The arithmetic's of elliptic curves", the question it self does not appear in the book but was given after studying about Mordell weil theorem and Lutz Nagel theorem

Comment: @Aphelli - I'm sorry but i don't understand what you mean, do you suggest writing x,y,z as rationals without 2 in the denominators? if so then i dont understand how that helps me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y^2 = 17 + 2x^2
\\
y^2 = 34 +z^2
$

Let $v$   be a common denominator, so that $vy, vx, vz$ are integers. Name $u = vy, $  then $w_1 = vx$ and $w_2 = vz.$   So far, I have $u^2 - 17 v^2 = 2 w_1^2$  while $u^2 - 34 v^2 =  w_2^2$

Here we are assuming that $u,v$ are **not both zero**!
If there is a common   divisor of $u,v$  then it also divides $w_1, w_2$  and we may divide through by that, achieving coprime $u,v$

Now, have  $\gcd(u,v) = 1$  and
$$u^2 - 17 v^2 = 2 w_1^2 \; , \; \; \;   u^2 - 34 v^2 =  w_2^2$$

We know at least one of $u,v$ is odd. Since $u^2 - 17 v^2$ must be even, we see that $u,v$   are **both odd**.

However,
$$ u^2 - 34 v^2 \equiv 1 - 2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4  $$
and cannot be a square.

Comment: Thank you very much!